# external service for saving form data, specifically files

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project where I'll need to build some forms that allow people to upload files, however these forms are hosted in an environment that does not have storage for the files.

I'm searching for a 3rd party service I can use save the files when the form is submitted, which will return me back a URL to access the file. I'd then save that URL with my form data to access the file later.

I'm look for recommendations for services for this as well as insights from anyone that has dealt with this sort of odd scenario.

Thanks in advance!